# Javascript validation not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

JavaScript validation & alert is working on Internet Explorer but not in Chrome.
Pls help me in understanding the problem and provide solution for the same.

```js
this.form1.i2.focus();
this.form1.i2.select();

function validateInput() {
  userInput = new String();
  userInput = this.form1.i2.value;

  if (userInput.match("Indica"))
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '(Note: This vehicle to be requested one hour before)';
  else if (userInput.match("Innova"))
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '(Note: This vehicle to be requested one hour before)';
  else if (userInput.match("Others"))
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '(Note: This vehicle to be requested one hour before)';
  else if (userInput.match("Tavera"))
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '';
  else if (userInput.match("Tempo"))
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<select name='i2' onChange='validateInput(this.value)' onClick="check2()">
  <option value='Select'>Select</option>
  <option value='Tavera'>Tavera</option>
  <option value='Innova'>Innova</option>
  <option value='Indica'>Indica</option>
  <option value='Indigo'>Indigo</option>
  <option value='Tempo'>Tempo</option>
  <option value='Etios'>Etios</option>
  <option value='Others'>Others</option>
</select>
<br>
```

Comment: Hi da! Did you check the Console in Chrome Dev Tools for errors?

Comment: please try this  window.alert = null;
alert('test'); // fail
delete window.alert; // true
alert('test'); // win

Comment: Where does form1 come from?

Comment: Select Name i2 is from form1.

Comment: I am not too good in programing can you help me in correcting the complete program pls.

Answer (score 0):

Change the second line in the function validateInput

```
    function validateInput() {
      userInput = new String();
      userInput = document.getElementById("i2").value;

      if (userInput.match("Indica"))
        document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '(Note: This vehicle to be requested one hour before)';
      else if (userInput.match("Innova"))
        document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '(Note: This vehicle to be requested one hour before)';
      else if (userInput.match("Others"))
        document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '(Note: This vehicle to be requested one hour before)';
      else if (userInput.match("Tavera"))
        document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '';
      else if (userInput.match("Tempo"))
        document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '';
    }
```

Alsao when you are calling ValidateInput on change of the dropdown , do not pass any argument as none is being passed in the function declaration